# ui-router triggers child state before parent state is resolved

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am trying to execute some initialization code in a parent state of the Angular ui-router. The initialization code is `orderService.getStoreInfo()` which returns a promise. Only when this promise is resolved, do I want to trigger the child state. However, what I am noticing is that the child state is triggered even before the parent's promise has resolved. What am I doing wrong? Here' my code:

```
function configure($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            resolve: {
                storeInfo: /* @ngInject */ function(orderService) {
                    console.log('home: resolve - orderService.getStoreInfo()');
                    return orderService.getStoreInfo();
                }
            }
        })

        .state('home.orders', {
            url: '^/',
            template: '<my-order-list data-orders="vm.orders"></my-order-list>',
            resolve: {
                orders: /* @ngInject */ function (orderService) {
                    console.log('home.orders: resolve - orderService.getOrders()');
                    return orderService.getOrders();
                }
            },
            controller: ['orders', function (orders) {
                this.orders = orders;
            }],
            controllerAs: 'vm',
        });
}
```

The console log is as follows:

```
home: resolve - orderService.getStoreInfo()
home.orders: resolve - orderService.getOrders()
... messages from orderService.getStoreInfo() ...
```

This clearly shows that the child state is firing even before the parent state has been resolved.

Comment: as far as I am aware, the only way to delay the resolve is to not return a promise.

Comment: Did you try to explicitly inject `storeInfo` to a resolve function of the child state? Not sure if it helps, just curious.

Comment: @YauheniLeichanok, that was exactly the issue! I re-read the ui-router docs and the clearly state that "The resolve keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the children." So thank you. If you put your suggestion as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views#inherited-resolved-dependencies): the `resolve` keys MUST be injected into the child states if you want to wait for the promises to be resolved before instantiating the children. So just explicitly inject `storeInfo` into a resolve function of the child state.